# Occam's Razor in Gaussian Processes model selection

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

Rasmussen Williams GPML book, Page 111 says,"... the marginal likelihood will still tend to favour the least complex model able to explain the data".

I don't understand how this is so obvious, can someone please explain?

Comment: Out of context, this appears to have many possible interpretations (and it might difficult to arrive at one that's actually true).  Could you therefore explain the context of this quotation?

Comment: @whuber the context is model selection and why does the optimization of marginal likelihood leads to a simpler model by default. Does it make sense?

Comment: I don't see how optimizing a marginal likelihood leads to a "simpler" model.  Often "simpler" means "uses fewer parameters," but optimization doesn't ordinarily do that.  Something seems to be missing.  "Simpler" than what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Page 113, Rasmussen and Williams say:

> The three terms of the marginal likelihood in eq. (5.8) have readily interpretable roles: the only term involving the observed targets is the data-fit $−y^TK^{−1}_y y/2$; $\log |K_y|/2$ is the complexity penalty depending only on the covariance function and the inputs and $n\log(2\pi)/2$ is a normalization constant.

So basically, the first term rewards a good fit, while the second term penalizes model complexity. The book goes into a bit more detail with an example.

Comment: Ah ok, the optimization function has a inbuilt regularizer, hence it gives a simpler model. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Feel free to mark the question as answered if you have no other followups!